# `knitr::include_url` produces inline frame without images

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

## Expected

According to the [rmarkdown cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/include-url.html), using `knitr::include_url` should produce an inline frame of the webpage (note that it works and contains images):

[image]

## Observed

But when I do the exact same thing in HTML document, I see no images in my inline frame, and I am not sure why:

[image]

## Details

In case it helps, here are some more details:

YAML for my document

```yaml
---
output: html_document
---
```

System details

```
 version  R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
 os       macOS Mojave 10.14.6        
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
 ui       RStudio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a change in a recent version of Pandoc (not that recent but a few months ago) that it will embed URLs as base64 data. I just [patched **knitr**](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/5df7d270ae7d10069b8231899ac568674c1690f6) to change this behavior. You can try the dev version of **knitr**:

```r
remotes::install_github('yihui/knitr')
```

Comment: Dear Yihui, thanks for your response. I updated to the development version of `knitr`, refreshed R session, and knitted again. But now *nothing* is included in the inline frame - there is just an empty box. (P.S. If it is of any relevance, my `pandoc` version is `2.11.4`.)

Comment: That is expected in the RStudio Viewer, because the viewer cannot show arbitrary external resources (it has a whitelist). You need to pop the content into your web browser to be able to view the iframe (use the arrow button on the right side of the broom button at the top).

Answer (score 1):

For those who can't update to last **knitr** version for any reason, you can fix this by adding the attributes yourself to the chunk using `out.extra` chunk option.

````markdown
```{r, out.extra="data-external=1"}
knitr::include_url("https://yihui.org/knitr/")
```
````

Just sharing this workaround in case updating to dev **knitr** is a problem and one wants to wait for CRAN version.